# JS - Making image move randomly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image that I want to move around randomly, for that I created a function where I pass variables as parameters and change the image style so it moves.

Here is my code for the image:

```js
//moving camel
var camel = document.getElementsByClassName('camel')[0];
var mL = camel.style.left;
var mT = camel.style.top;
var op = camel.style.opacity;
var marginH = 0;
var marginV = 0;
var x;

var direction = (dir, margin) => {
    console.log(dir);
    x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    if (x === 0) {
        dir = dir + 5;

    }
    else {
        dir = dir - 5;
    }

    margin = `${dir}px`;
    op = 1;
    console.log(`moving ${dir}`)
}

setInterval(function () {
    direction(marginH, mL)
}, 1000);
```

```css
.camel{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    transition: all 2s ease-in;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<img class="camel" src="https://phys.org/newman/csz/news/tmb/2012/camel.jpg"></image>
```

For reasons I do not understand everytime the function runs the variable marginH is set to 0 so the function isn't updating the variable.
Also there is no effect on the image itself.

Comment: _"everytime the function runs the variable marginH is set to 0"_ - You never set the value to anything other than zero. Why do you expect it to be something different?

Comment: Hello Mr Turnip. Yes but it was set outside of the function. Inside the function I am adding 5 or subtracting 5.

Comment: No, you are adding or substracting 5 to `dir` which is a *copy* of `marginH` as it is passed *by value*

Comment: @BrunoSousa A simple illustration ... https://jsfiddle.net/3rror404/5pch3md0/3/

Comment: @Turnip you probably meant `val += 100` instead of `val + 100` in your fiddle

Comment: Sorry, yes I did. Updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only defining a `margin` variable, but you've forgot to apply it to the element:

```
camel.style.margin = margin;
```

```js
//moving camel
var camel = document.getElementsByClassName('camel')[0];
var mL = camel.style.left;
var mT = camel.style.top;
var op = camel.style.opacity;
var marginH = 0;
var marginV = 0;
var x;

var direction = (dir, margin) => {
    console.log(dir);
    x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    if (x === 0) {
        dir = dir + 5;
    }
    else {
        dir = dir - 5;
    }
    
    // Apply new margin
    margin = `${dir}px`;
    camel.style.margin = margin;
    
    // Please see additional info below the code why this isn't working
    op = 1;
    console.log(`moving ${dir}`)
}

setInterval(function () {
    direction(marginH, mL)
}, 1000);
```

```css
.camel{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    transition: all 2s ease-in;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<img src='https://placehold.it/150x150' class='camel' />
```

---

The same for the `op` variable, you can apply a new opacity on a elemteny like so:

```
camel.style.opacity = "0.5";
```

Comment: This solved it Mr @Ostone0 thanks a lot. Also learned something new.